# Duplicate all rows and change but change store_id

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, rows

I have this table name: `copy_stores`

```
copy_id | store_id
11221        2
11222        2
112223       2
```

there is about 2000 records, but I like to duplicate all the records but on the newly duplicated change the `store_id` to `1` where it's `2`

I have tried this, but it won't work:

```sql
insert into copy_stores(`copy_id`, `store_id`)
SELECT 1, `copy_id`, `store_id`
from copy_stores
where store_id = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You want '1' to be the new store_id, so need to select it after the copy_id:

```
INSERT INTO copy_stores(copy_id, store_id)
SELECT copy_id, 1
FROM review_store
WHERE store_id = 2
```